# Count document which no repeate field mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

How to count document which no repeate field ?

```
[
   {
       name : 'John',
       age : 21,
   },
   {
       name : 'Ethan',
       age : 23,
   },
   {
       name : 'Jack',
       age : 21,
   },
]
```

I want to count how many type of age are there like

```
db.countSomeThing()
```

result I expect is 2 because 21 repeate 2 time so just count 1 age = 21 and 1 age = 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$age"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/945aLNktNwi)**